# Dual graph of a NOT connected plane multigraph is connected?

Tags: graph-theory

In my book and many previous questions, they seems to naturally assume that the dual of a plane graph is connected.
But is it true for a NOT connected plane graph?
I think it is natural since there is an outer face of a plane graph and the corresponding vertex in the dual is connected to all vertices corresponding to the faces adjacent to the outer face.
I found a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819848/prove-that-the-dual-graph-of-any-planar-graph-is-connected) here, but answer sounds only if $G$ is connected, while the question asks the case of 'any' planar graphs.
Can you suggest me any rigorous or nice proofs about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove it by induction over the number of connected components.

Consider a connected component $C$ of $G$ and remove it along with all its edges.

The resulting graph $G'$ satisfies that it's dual has only one connected component by induction hypothesis.

Let $F$ be the face of the graph which contains the vertices of $C$. The faces of $G$ are the faces of $G'$ except for $F$, along with some faces which are subsets of $F$. The faces of $G$ contained in $F$ are all "connected by paths" because $C$ is a connected planar graph. Now you just need to note that if there exists another face in $G'$ then one of them was connected to $F$, and hence is connected to a face of $G$ that is a subset of $F$, and so indeed the dual has only one connected component.

Comment: Can I ask one more: How can we prove that 'If $G$ is connected then $G^*$ is connected'? The proof I linked is not concrete and contains some circular reasonings.